# Can't access inputfield values set by interpolation {{}}

Tags: angular, forms, string-interpolation

I am working on a really simple app, it includes a form with formArray.
In the formArray a product name and amount can be selected. When both selected,  a third input field  - **total** - calculates the total price of the stuff (product price * amount), using

```
<input matInput placeholder="total"
  type="number"
  formControlName="total"
  value="{{getProductPrice(purchaseForm.value.product[i].productId) * purchaseForm.value.product[i].amount}}">
```

I would like to sum the **total** input field (price) of all items in the formArray. The value renders OK, if I change any product and/or amount, it changes automatically.

My problem is, when I try to access the values of the **total** inputfields, i get 0.  If I change the value manually (pasting, typing etc.), than I can access it right away.

I can access the other field (fex. I can calculate the SUM amount of all the products)

Is the problem caused because the way I set the value of the field?

Does somebody has any clue why that is?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `value`, you are binding to an `HTML` attribute called `value`, which will update the DOM but will never update your form's value. To update your form value, you can use `ngModel` in conjunction with reactive forms like so, but I don't recommend it:

```html
<input matInput placeholder="total"
  type="number"
  formControlName="total"
  [ngModel]="getProductPrice(purchaseForm.value.product[i].productId) * purchaseForm.value.product[i].amount">
```

You should **never** be setting a value from within a view like that. But, that code will work. A more correct way of doing things would probably be to watch for value changes in the form and set the total based on the new values. Something along the lines of this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // Watch our form and set value of total based on qty and price.
  // NOTE: In real life be sure to unsubscribe from this subscription when component is destroyed.
  // You ALSO probably only want to respond to certain value changes here.
  this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(formValues => {
    if (someValueIndicatingWeNeedToUpdateTotal === true) {
      this.form.get('total').setValue(1 * 2); // Obviously replace this with real logic
    }
  })
}
```

Anyway, I've created a [working example you can play around with on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9qddo9).

Comment: Dean, NOT use for one input [(ngModel)] and formControlName, and not use [(ngModel)] with a function (It's allowed use [ngModel], but not the "bannana sintax". And yes the correct way is subscribe to value change to get the total and subtotal, but I can understand that total belong to the FormArray and, of course, the total must be a literal, not a input

Comment: @Eliseo yes, I don't recommend using `ngModel` with reactive forms. And setting the property value in your field is also not good. Nice catch on the two-way binding versus one-way binding. I updated my answer to only have one-way binding.

Comment: BTW - one other possible option here would be to have total not exist in the form at all (since it's a calculated field, and thus doesn't really make sense as a form field).

Comment: I say that NOT put it (not that  it's not recomended, see https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel). Using a input with [(ngModel)] inside a `<form [formGroup]="form">` should used only to manage a variable that not belong to the form (and in this case we need put `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone:true}"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
//create an array of totals
totals:number[]=[];
total:number; //<--use a variable to store the total

//After create the form Array
this.yourFormArray.valueChanges(res=>{
   let total=0;
   res.forEach((x:any,index:number)=>{
     //use the "+" to convert to number res.amount;
     totals[index]=(+x.amount)*(this.getProductPrice(x.productId));
     total+=totals[index]
   })
   this.total=total;
}
```